# Appengine ndb - How to ensure unique username and email without ancestors?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

In my Appengine (using ndb) application I store users and both username and email need to be unique.
I also need to be able to update progress (save level if higher than previously stored level), change email and pw and delete account.

I noticed that it is not possible to query without ancestors in a transaction. But creating an ancestor is NOT a solution since that would limit the number of writes to 1 per second which is not OK if the app gets popular. So I need another solution.

Is it possible to use the Key? Yes, but that only makes the username unique, how can I make sure noone is reusing the email for another account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a cross group transaction for this along with an entity that exists solely for reserving email addresses.

For your `User` entity, you could use the username as the key name.  When creating a user, you also create an `EmailReservation` entity that has the user's email address as a key name.

You then use a cross-group transaction to create a new user:

```
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def create_user(user_name, email):
    user = User.get_by_id(user_name)
    email_reservation = EmailReservation.get_by_id(email)
    if user or email_reservation:
        # Either the user_name or email is already in use so stop
        return None
    # Create the user and reserve the email address so others can't use it
    user = User(id=user_name)
    email_reservation = EmailReservation(id=email)
    ndb.put_multi(user, email_reservation)
    return user
```